How to Modify Cypher Query to Return Results with Virtual Relationships in Neo4j 3.5?
This is my original Cypher statement:
WITH ['aab40c4d65d5c0a428ed84dc0109b0c4', '000415fee2b0272cdcc2439f521b2e2e'] AS param
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['ent'], {nodeid: 'test'}) YIELD node AS a
MATCH (first:ent) WHERE first.nodeid IN param
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(first, 'teninvmerge', {conprop: "0.5"}, a) YIELD rel AS b
MATCH p = (a)-[b]-(first:ent)<-[inv:teninvmerge*1..5]-(end)
RETURN p

As you can see, I created a virtual edge, and through this virtual edge, I performed a traversal query. However, if I change the final statement to MATCH p = (a)<-[inv:teninvmerge*1..5]-(end), I get no results. I would like to know how I can modify my Cypher so that MATCH p = (a)<-[inv:teninvmerge*1..5]-(end) can also yield results.
I can obtain traversal results through virtual edges.

The virtual relationship that you created: teninvmerge does not exists in the database so you can change your query to return a, b and first.
WITH ['aab40c4d65d5c0a428ed84dc0109b0c4', '000415fee2b0272cdcc2439f521b2e2e'] AS param
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['ent'], {nodeid: 'test'}) YIELD node AS a
MATCH (first:ent) WHERE first.nodeid IN param
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(first, 'teninvmerge', {conprop: "0.5"}, a) YIELD rel AS b
//MATCH p = (a)-[b]-(first:ent)<-[inv:teninvmerge*1..5]-(end)
//rel: teninvmerge does not exists
RETURN a, b, first


The query I want to perform is to penetrate 5 levels through this virtual relationship.
